# How to exclude samples that are already sampled before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, sample

First, I am beginner as a developer using ruby-on-rails. 
I am using blahblah.sample(x) to get (x) samples from blahblah.
What i want to do is, I am using a loop to put several different numbers in an array. I will use the sample method to get (x) numbers. 
Here is the point I don't want to put the same number many times in the array.
I know that if i put the random numbers and use uniq method this problem will be solved, but I want to exclude the number that i have in the array before I put it in the array. How can I solve this problem? I want to recognize that I have the number in the array or not before I put the number inside the array.

What I am eventually trying to do is 
When I am getting 10 sample of users to analyze their data. So I don't want to analyze the user that is analyzed already. I want to recognize if they are analyzed or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think its a job for [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and [`Set#add?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) method:

**Set**

> Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates.
>   This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and
>   Hash's fast lookup.

**Set#add?**

> Adds the given object to the set and returns self. If the object is
>   already in the set, returns nil.

```
> set = Set.new([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7])
=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}>
> set.add? 7
=> nil
> set.add? 8
=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}>
```

Comment: Once you have constructed the set, you will need to extract its elements for processing. You could do that with `arr = set.to_a`, but since sets are not ordered, `arr[i]` is not guaranteed to equal the ith element added to the set. Because (presumably random) sampling is involved, order may not be important, but I thought it's worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C):

```
[1,2,3] | [4]
#⇒ [1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3] | [1]
#⇒ [1,2,3]
```

Note that it expects an array as RHO:

```
10.times.inject([]) { |memo, i| memo | [i % 3] }
#⇒ [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I first think about `union`, it's a very handy feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by using include? method on that array to check number before putting it the array. like this

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a.include?(8) != true
a << 8
p a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: you can add one more condition to it for exclude number if it is present in that array.

Comment: `!= true` is redundant and not ruby idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @Зелёный's method is to use a hash, which would preserve the order by which elements are added to the sample and also provide some additional information that may be of interest.

Suppose the values received are given by the array

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,3,6,3,6,7]
```

These could be fed to a counting hash:

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>2, 7=>1}
```

For Ruby v1.9+ the hash keys will be ordered as they appear in `arr.uniq` (which itself maintains order of `arr`).

The non-repeating sample is given by

```
h.keys
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and `h` tells you how many times each of these values were generated by the enumerator.

Answer (score -1):

You can shuffle your array and pop elements from it.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle!
elem = arr.pop # 2
elem = arr.pop # 1
elem = arr.pop # 4
elem = arr.pop # 3
```

Comment: How this answers the question?

Comment: This is exactly what is asked, everytime you call pop a different random value of the array will be returned. Instead of everytime check if the array includes the element (O(n)), it shuffles the array one time and always get one element (O(1)). Pop method can be called x times to get the expected behavior.

Comment: I know how `Array#pop` works and what is it’s complexity, thanks. Below is the exact quote from the OP: “I want to **exclude** the number that i have in the array **before I put it in the array**. How can I solve this problem?”

Comment: This is a workaround, another way of solving the problem without creating another array and veryfing everytime, a better approach IMO.

Comment: There could be 100500 examples of when this approach is not working. First of all, nobody promised you ever have the initial array to shuffle. Items might come from a stream, for starters.